# Ethereum Explorer without a full node

Tags: explorers

Assume a blockchain is running on a set of servers.

**Question** 1: Can a thin client (who does not have a full node like Geth) use Ethereum explorer to see the transactions sending to the blockchain?

---

Assume a client who has a full node deployed a contract.

**Question** 2: How can a full node determine who has sent some transactions to its contract?

---

Regarding question 1: I'm aware of [this](https://github.com/carsenk/explorer), but it requires a full node.

Answer (score 1):

Question1. Yes. I am assumimg you mean a remote block explorer. In this case you could more simply use a remote node service like infura

Question 2. Your full node will receive  transactions from the network, including the one relevant to your contract , if any. Some of these transactions will appear directly in mined blocks, while other will be relayed outside of any blocks, i.e with a pending status.

Comment: Thank you! but your answer did not answer my 2nd question.

Comment: Ok. Lets make sure we understand each other well for the 2nd question. When you say "its contract", what do you mean? A node does not possess any contract. And when you say "who send the transaction", do you mean the ethereum account or something else ?